# How to create archive child pages with good Yoast SEO meta?

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, child-pages, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, archive-template

I want to create children pages to some archives on wordpress with Yoast SEO.

Today, i have `/tags/{tagName}` and i want to add sub pages to this archive.

The goal is to have:

- `/tags/{tagName}` main tag page with some infos
- `/tags/{tagName}/news` with a list of post
- `/tags/{tagName}/videos` with a list of custom post type
- `/tags/{tagName}/bios` with a list of custom taxonomy

Each children need to get his own yoast seo meta (title, description, canonical) to not have duplicate metas.

How can i archive this ?

My idea was to add rewrite rules to add these slugs to archive pages:

`/tags/({$post_type_nicename})/news/?$ => index.php?post_tag=$matches[1]&sub_page=news`

`/tags/({$post_type_nicename})/news/{$wp_rewrite->pagination_base}/?([0-9]{1,})/?$ => index.php?post_tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]&sub_page=news`

And use `sub_page` query var to know on wich sub page i am.
But, with this kind of solution, yoast seo metas are the same on each page.

Thank you!